# Pass date testing angular unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, date

I have a ternary that seems to be returning a passing test, but it is failing.

```
$scope.depart = (typeof serverShortDate !== 'undefined') ? new Date(serverShortDate) : new Date();



AssertionError: expected Wed, 30 Mar 2016 21:26:12 GMT to deeply equal Wed, 30 Mar 2016 21:26:12 GMT
```

Here is my simple spec

```
    expect(scope.depart).to.deep.equal(new Date());
```

All that I can imagine is that somewhere is a difference.  The error message shows the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have that `===` on objects checks that the two objects are the same object. `===` works slightly differently for objects when compared to strings or numbers.

Your test appears compares a new Date object to `scope.depart`, by definition these objects are not the same object and can never be 'deeply' equal.

You could change your test to:

```
expect(scope.depart.valueOf()).to.deep.equal((new Date()).valueOf());
```

to check that both dates represent the same date/time.

Comment: I see what you mean on that as that expect fails

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the responses to test.

```
expect(scope.depart.toString()).to.deep.equal(new Date().toString());
```